# Full list of symbols recognized by C

Tags: c, symbols

I'm writing a C tokenizer and I want to have a full list of all of the symbols that C recognizes, such as '+', '-', '*', '/', '!', '!=', '==', '++', etc. Note that I don't mean keywords (I've already found a list of those). I've looked around but haven't found a single comprehensive list, and I don't quite trust myself to enumerate all of them. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Um, what's wrong with looking at the C standard? (You have to choose which one).

Comment: You can look in Annex A in the standard.

Comment: you have forgotten the braces '(' and '{' and '[' sowie the komma and semicolon. Tilde and ampersand, maybe even the #-sign

Comment: @PeterMiehle "sowie the komma"?

Comment: upps. sorry. "also the comma".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Lex scanner list of tokens for ANSI C 2011 can be found here: http://www.quut.com/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l-2011.html

**Edited:**

As pointed out by Jens: The list does neither show the digraph nor the trigraph tokens:

[image]
[image]

Tables from "[C in a Nutshell](http://books.google.de/books?id=4Mfe4sAMFUYC&pg=PT29&lpg=PT29&dq=c%20tokens%20##%20digraph&source=bl&ots=tPQKYtM3pg&sig=QAf7XVlcfHVWPJ1bwvpVYPKNTtA&hl=de&sa=X&ei=SV40Ufa6C8WA4gTyooDwBw&ved=0CIMBEOgBMAc#v=onepage&q&f=false)"

Comment: +1, but that list is missing the tokens `#`, `##` and their digraph equivalents.

Answer (score 1):

if you have the K&R (the bible, whichever edition (f.e. ANSI)), you have a complete list with precedence at the end of the book (in my german edition it is appendix A).

You may also take a look at the gnu-c-compiler source, which has a scanner/grammar you can peek into.

Answer (score 1):

The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_programming_language#Character_set) contains the following list

> Punctuation: ~ ! @ # % ^ & * ( ) - + = : ; " ' < > , . ? | / \ { } [ ]

although the definitive authoritative source is the C standard, ISO IEC 9899. Being an ISO standard, it costs money to get, although there are some drafts versions freely available on the internet.

The drafts are almost the same as the final standard but not quite. Generally since you do not know exactly what the difference is without having the standard to compare with, you should limit your trust on drafts and at least seek additional sources of information. 
Although for something as basic as the syntax it should be fine.

An alternative way (and probably the best in my opinion) of getting the C standard is to get the book [The New C Standard: An Economic and Cultural Commentary](http://www.knosof.co.uk/cbook/cbook.html) which is freely available and contains the whole (final) standard together with lots of commentary on the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is short, let me provide a complete list here in place. From the C11 standard:

> (6.4.6) punctuator: one of

```
[ ] ( ) { } . ->
++ -- & * + - ~ !
/ % << >> < > <= >=
 ==
 !=
 ^
 |
 &&
 ||
? : ; ...
= *= /= %= += -= <<=
 >>=
 &=
 ^=
 |=
, # ##
<: :> <% %> %: %:%:
```

in particular notice the `#` and `##` tokens that the other answers missed, and the digraph tokens at the end.